# Doctrine 2.5.11 introduces problems on PHP 7.0

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, php-7, php-7.1

Today was updating an server installation and broke my whole setup. Noticed that doctrine/orm ~2.5.6 loaded 2.5.11 which requires

- Installing doctrine/collections (v1.5.0)
- Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.5.0)
- Installing doctrine/common (v2.8.1)
- Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.1.0)
- Installing doctrine/orm (v2.5.11)

doctrine/collections and all the other packages require PHP 7.1. Thats why my application was not working anymore. Upgrading to 7.1 was not an option for now so we fixed the dependencies to:

, "doctrine/orm"                        :   "2.5.10"
, "doctrine/annotations"                :   "~1.4.0"
, "doctrine/collections"                :   "~1.4.0"
, "doctrine/common"                     :   "~2.7.0"

Now my question: **Is the version number from doctrine/orm 2.5.11 not wrong? Shouldn't it be 2.6 since it requires dependencies which do not work in 7.0 and it will break installations?**

The problem came up since (on Mac) the php version is different from the apache version. Thats why I think the semantics in the version numbering should be improved or the requirements in the doctrine/orm package need to be less loose.

I am interested to understand how this can be done better from my side.

Just for google will add the Exception message: Return value of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerFile() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Annotations\void, none returned

Answer (score 0):

## A. To your questions about versions

*1. Is the version number from `doctrine/orm 2.5.11` not wrong*

*2. Shouldn't it be 2.6 since it requires dependencies which do not work in 7.0 and it will break installations?*

---

#### 1. major.minor.patch

This is [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) in one words.

- If you FIX for something or just want to tag new version to be downloadable via composer - **patch++**
- If you ADD NEW feature - **minor++**
- If you REMOVE some old features, that won't work - **major++**

Bumping any package version is the first case, since composer won't allow to install packages that would break anything.

#### 2. `composer update` takes care of this

When your code runs after `composer update` (when you use common version locks like `^2.5`), there is no need for **major++** version.

If you have PHP 7.0, and you run `composer update`, all will work.

Composer won't download `doctrine/orm 2.5.11`, because it doesn't meet your local conditions.

---

**And if you update your system to PHP 7.1** any time in the future and run `composer update`, composer will upgrade to `doctrine/orm 2.5.11` (or greater) and your code will work.

You can also find similar explanation in [official post in Doctrine's documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html#why-dropping-php-support-in-a-minor-version-is-not-a-bc-break).

---

## B. How to solve this with various versions on local and server?

You can enforce preferred version in `composer.json` by using [platform](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) option.

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.0"
    }
}
```

This will prefer PHP 7.0 packages on both your local system and server.